# ¿Cómo mostrar resultados en un input mediante Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando simular un cajero automático sencillo, en el que se pueda depositar, retirar y consultar el saldo.

Bien, lo he estado haciendo por medio de *inputs* usando [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), pero mi código no funciona.

He aquí el código, por favor díganme en qué estoy mal.

```js
        var saldo = 0,
          deposito, retiro;

        function depositar() {
          deposito = document.getElementByName("deposito").value;
          saldo = saldo + deposito;
        }

        function retirar() {
          retiro = document.getElementByName("retirar").value;
          if (retiro > saldo) {
            alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
          } else {
            saldo = saldo - retiro;
          }
        }

        function verificar() {
          document.getElementByName("verificar").value = saldo;
        }
```

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito" />

        <input type="submit" value="Depositar" onclick="depositar()">
        </br>
        </br>
        su saldo actual es</br>
        <input tupe "text" name "verificar" onclick="verificar()">
        <input type="submit" value="verificar">
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="retirar" onclick="retirar()">
        <input type="submit" value="retirar">
    </form>
```

Comment: tu código tiene errores: <input tupe "text" name "verificar"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En el código hay los siguientes errores:

**1. Error de tipeo**

Dice `tupe "text"`, debe decir `type="text"`. También dice `name "verificar"`, debe decir `name="verificar"`

**Corrección:**

```
<input type="text" name="verificar" onclick="verificar()">
```

**2. Usar `type="button"`**

Cambia el `type` de los botones a `button`. Ya que todo el código es por lado cliente, no necesitas que el botón haga un POST HTTP así que conviene más usar `type="button"`

**Correcciones:**

```
<input type="button" value="Depositar" onclick="depositar()">

...

<input type="button" value="verificar">

...

<input type="button" value="retirar">
```

**3. Ubicación de los `onclick` handlers**

Los `onclick` de `verficar` y `retirar` deben ir el los botones y no en las cajas de texto

**Correcciones:**

```
<input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="verificar()">

...

<input type="button" value="retirar" onclick="retirar()">
```

**4. Método inexistente**

No existe `document.getElementByName`. El método correcto es `getElementsByName` con *Elements* en plural. Debido a que devuelve un array con varios resultados debes escoger el primer elemento que es el que tiene el `input` que estás buscando

**Correcciones:**

```
deposito = document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value;

...

retiro = document.getElementsByName("retirar")[0].value;

...

document.getElementsByName("verificar")[0].value = saldo;
```

**5. Colisión de nombres**

Los inputs `verificar` y `retirar` se llaman igual que las funciones. Tienes que ponerles nombres diferentes ya están haciendo conflicto a la hora de ejecutar el `onclick()`

Por ejemplo yo les he cambiado el nombre a los inputs en su declaración y en el código javascript.

**Correcciones:**

```
function retirar() {
    retiro = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("retiro")[0].value);
    ...
}

...

function verificar() {
    document.getElementsByName("verificacion")[0].value = saldo;
}

...

<input type="text" name="verificacion">

...

<input type="text" name="retiro" >
```

**6. Validación de los `input`**

El usuario podría ingresar valores que no son números en los inputs por lo que conviene validarlos con la función `isNaN()`

Por ejemplo si el valor ingresado no es un número se muestra una `alert` con el mensaje de error.

```
function depositar() {
    deposito = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value);

    if (isNaN(deposito)) {
        alert("El valor ingresado no es número válido");
        return;
    }

    saldo = saldo + deposito;
}

function retirar() {
    retiro = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("retiro")[0].value);

    if (isNaN(retiro)) {
        alert("El valor ingresado no es número válido");
        return;
    }

    if (retiro > saldo) {
        alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
        return;
    }

    saldo = saldo - retiro;    
}
```

**7. Tag malformado**

El tag `</br>` está malformado. Lo correcto es `<br />`

**8. Errores de consistencia**

El texto de los botones es inconsistente. "Depositar" comienza con mayúsculas pero "verficar" y "retirar" están en minúsculas

**Correcciones:**

```
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()">

...

<input type="button" value="Retirar" onclick="retirar()">
```

El código completo te lo muestro a continuación:

```js
    var saldo = 0,
    deposito, retiro;

    function depositar() {
        deposito = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value);

        if (isNaN(deposito)) {
            alert("El valor ingresado no es número válido");
            return;
        }

        saldo = saldo + deposito;
    }

    function retirar() {
        retiro = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("retiro")[0].value);

        if (isNaN(retiro)) {
            alert("El valor ingresado no es número válido");
            return;
        }

        if (retiro > saldo) {
            alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
            return;
        }

        saldo = saldo - retiro;    
    }

    function verificar() {
        document.getElementsByName("verificacion")[0].value = saldo;
    }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito" />

    <input type="button" value="Depositar" onclick="depositar()">
    <br />
    <br />
    su saldo actual es<br />
    <input type="text" name="verificacion">
    <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="retiro" >
    <input type="button" value="Retirar" onclick="retirar()">
</form>
```

Comment: Bravo!! qué respuesta más completa, muy agradecido con usted amigo!

Comment: Si te pareció buena puedes votar por esta respuesta, y/o aceptarla =)

Comment: Claro que sí, podría explicarme cómo hago eso? y con mucho gusto

Comment: Para votar puedes hacer clic en la triángulo hacia arriba que está al comienzo de la pregunta en el lado izquierdo. Y para aceptarla puedes hacer clic en el check blanco que sale debajo de las flechas. Si otras respuestas también te sirvieron puedes votar por varias, pero solo puedes escoger una como la aceptada. Escoge la que mas te convenza. Puedes leer mas sobre esto en el [Tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Listo! aun no tengo 15 de reputación por eso no la aparecerá, pero el check ya

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarse el tiempo y dar una respuesta bien detallada :)

Comment: De nada. te recomiendo que para la próxima uses un buen IDE o editor de código que te ayude a resaltar los errores de sintaxis que tienes en tu código y que también aprendas a usar las herramientas de desarrollo de los navegadores (Salen al presionar la tecla F12 generalmente). Ahí podrías haber depurado el código y detectado los errores JavaScript que tenías.

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias, eso estoy comenzando a implementar!

Comment: con cosas de dinero mejor agregar confirmaciones no?
el monto ingresado deberia desaparecer una vez haya hecho el deposito, para evitar duplicados y errores , otra cosa es la confirmacion del retiro y del deposito , vale ahora veo la fecha de la publicacion . un saludo, quedo bien

Comment: @JuanOrtiz bueno la UI es bastante mala, debe ser sólo un ejemplo. Lo importante era que funcione el código JavaScript no modificar tooooodo.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes una serie de errores en tu código. Es `getElementsByName` con s, en plural, recuerda que devolverá un array, por ende sería `document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value` ya que deseamos el primer elemento por ejemplo.

La línea `<input tupe"text" name"verificar" onclick="verificar()">` es `type` y name necesita el `=`. Lo que quedaría `<input type="text" name="verificar" onclick="verificar()">`.

Por último necesitas usar `parseFloat` o `parseInt` para que pueda servir la suma y la resta, sino concatena los valores, o en su defecto usar `input type='number'`;

```
var saldo = 0, deposito, retiro;

function depositar() {
  deposito = document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value;
  saldo = (parseFloat(saldo) + parseFloat(deposito));
  verificar();
}

function retirar() {
  retiro = document.getElementsByName("retirar")[0].value;
  if (retiro > saldo) {
    alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
  } else {
    saldo = (parseFloat(saldo) - parseFloat(retiro));
    verificar();
  }
}

function verificar() {
  document.getElementsByName("verificar")[0].value = saldo;
}
```

[Demo en vivo](http://codepen.io/FreakDroid/pen/vLyOXZ)

**Nota**: modifique el ejemplo para que no use un `form` sino un `div`, para que lo veas mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Para efectos de tus pruebas no deberías estar usando `<input type="submit" .. />` ya que, según veo, todo lo quieres hacer por el lado del cliente, es decir, no veo en tu código ninguna vista/cotrolador que reciba tu `POST`.

Por lo tanto con esto bastaría para tus pruebas:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Banquito</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito">
    <button type="button" onclick="depositarDinero()">Depositar</button>
    </br>
    </br>
    Su saldo actual es</br>
    <input type="text" name="verificar">
    <button type="button" onclick="verificarSaldo()">Verificar</button>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="retirar">
    <button type="button" onclick="retirarDinero()">Retirar</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var saldo = 0;

    function depositarDinero() {
      var deposito = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("deposito")[0].value);
      saldo += deposito;
    }

    function retirarDinero() {
      var retiro = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("retirar")[0].value);
      if (retiro > saldo) {
        alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
      } else {
        saldo -= retiro;
      }
    }

    function verificarSaldo() {
      document.getElementsByName("verificar")[0].value = saldo;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Notas**:

- El método `onclick` debe ir en el `<button onclick="funcion()"` y no el `<input type="text">`
- Las variables `deposito` y `retiro` no deberían ser globales ya que solo las usas en el scope de tus funciones.
- Estoy usando `parseInt` para parsear los depósitos y retiros pero tal vez esto te quede chico cuando empieces a usar fracciones
- Es [recomendable](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom=) que pongas los `scripts` en la parte final de tu `body`
- El método correcto es `getElementsByName` como mencionó @rnrneverdies

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!! muy completa tu respuesta. He corregido todo a como me aconsejas, pero sigue sin hacer nada cuando doy click en los botones

Comment: @Power_HR que raro, el snippet funciona muy bien, intenta copiar todo y pegarlo en tu template

Answer (score -1):

```js
        var saldo = 0,
          deposito, retiro;

        function depositar() {
          deposito = document.getElementByName("deposito").value;
          saldo = saldo + deposito;
        }

        function retirar() {
          retiro = document.getElementByName("retirar").value;
          if (retiro > saldo) {
            alert("Su fondo disposible no es suficiente");
          } else {
            saldo = saldo - retiro;
          }
        }

        function verificar() {
          document.getElementByName("verificar").value = saldo;
        }
```

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="deposito" placeholder="Ingrese un deposito" />

        <input type="submit" value="Depositar" onclick="depositar()">
        </br>
        </br>
        su saldo actual es</br>
        <input tupe "text" name "verificar" onclick="verificar()">
        <input type="submit" value="verificar">
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="retirar" onclick="retirar()">
        <input type="submit" value="retirar">
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola escorreky. Por favor brinda una explicación para tu código, porque no se comprende mucho a simple vista lo que intentas realizar.